# Open document from drop down list under Search text box

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

I use the legacy Open dialog box to find and open documents. I type a search term into the Search box and then for some reason results will immediately appear under the text box in a drop down list, I’ll see the file I want, but when I click on it the file doesn’t open. In fact I get an error message that “Word can’t do this because a dialog box is open.” I have to execute the search and then open the document from the file list.
Is there trick, registry hack, utility, to being able to open a document from the drop down results list? I can right click on them for Open file location or Copy path, but using them isn’t easier than the regular method to open the document. This behavior makes no sense to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I, too, have had this happen and I understand your frustration.*

Those are search suggestions. You can complete the search by pressing Enter. You can click on the suggestion to make that the search parameter.

Once the search is done, If you click on one in the found list, it will fill in the name in the File Open dialog and Enter will open it, as will pressing Enter once the name is in the Filename part of the dialog. Right-click on one of the found items in the list, followed by Open gives you the error message. You need to use the Open button in the dialog box.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1192776)

Comment: I get “Word can’t do this because a dialog box is open.” Personally, I wish Word didn't show anything till I finished the search as it just teases me.

Comment: @music2myear It did answer the question, as was understood by user26.... Word does not use the File Open dialog searches the way desired. I have expanded the answer, however.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but all you did was tell me to do the extra steps I'm already complaining about. To add insult to injury right clicking on the file in the drop down only lets you copy the path or open the file location, both extra steps. I want to open the file directly from that list.